# Cplex quadratic constraints in python, sparepair and sparsetriple

Tags: python, constraints, sparse-matrix, cplex, quadratic-programming

I am using Cplex in Python to solve an SVM problem with reduced dimensions.
As a part of my algorithm, I have to add quadratic constraints to my objective function.
So to say, I want to add something like "(w1+w2)^2

Comment: I think you're looking for the [Cplex.objective.set_quadratic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.ObjectiveInterface-class.html#set_quadratic) function. There are examples in the documentation there that should be sufficient, but you can also look at the `qpex1.py` example that is included in the CPLEX installer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking to Cplex.constraints.set_quadratic